# How to pipe stdout from one command into a clean terminal view?

Tags: terminal

Currently writing a CLI application that provides a better wrapper for some Git functionality. As this is a CLI, the user uses their terminal to use the application.

What I need to be able to do is pipe the output of certain commands into "clean" and interactive sub-programs. For example, if the user has my UI up, but presses a key, I need my UI to entirely swap with that of `git add --patch [file_name]`. When the user is done (as that is a step-by-step process that eventually concludes) I need to swap back to my application's UI.

Problem is, I don't know where or what to pipe this output to. If I pipe it into the terminal, it clashes with the existing CLI app's `stdout` and that does not work.

A separate but related feature was to show diff logs. To solve this issue of a clean and interactive terminal for that, I piped the `stdout` into `less` and this worked perfectly. Just can't find a way to do that for something more complex like `git add --patch`.

Let me know if more details are needed. Mods got grumpy last time when I added (apparently too much) information, so this is super cut down.

Comment: You need to create a pseudo terminal (PTY).

Comment: Okay, never heard of that before. Thanks. Is there some standard way of doing that, or is it something that you generally have to roll yourself? Can't find a whole lot of beginner-level documentation for that, but probably my fault. I'll work on that though, appreciate the pointer.

Comment: There is a standard way for POSIX compatible systems. It's a very generic feature. https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/windows-command-line-introducing-the-windows-pseudo-console-conpty/ and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21545897/how-to-control-interactive-console-input-output-from-python-on-windows for Windows. Article on Wiki: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudoterminal. Unix manual: https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/pty.7.html. **Tons** of documentation available!

Comment: Alright, well this is all way over my head. I assumed there was just something simple and cross platform I could pipe one command into and have everything work. Apparently that's not the case. Thanks for your help though.

Comment: That is how to achieve it properly. But you see, even Microsoft realizes that they need a feature. :-)

Answer (score -1):

#### Use a pager

Most git commands with multi-screen output will automatically invoke a user-configured *pager* like `less` or `more`.

For those that don't, you could explicitly pipe them to `less`. Less's default behavior is to restore the terminal when it exits.

```sh
git add --patch [file_name] 2>&1 | less
```

#### Use curses

Use [curses](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/curses.html#starting-and-ending-a-curses-application) to clear the screen at startup and restore it at shutdown. For example, in Python:

```py
import curses

# Clear the screen.
scr = curses.initscr()
scr.clear()
scr.refresh()

# Application code here.
import time
time.sleep(1)

# Restore the screen.
curses.endwin()
```

(If you're not using Python you can probably find native curses bindings in whatever language you're using.)

Comment: I'll look into Curses, thanks. Using Rust, but I know there's some sort of Curses support. The first command you show just locks up my terminal though, might be something with my terminal locally, but I definitely can't get anything out of that. Blank screen and no way to escape. Have to close the entire window.

Comment: Using curses for this is simply not enough. You will still need a control terminal and a pseudo one to allow another **interactive** program to work as is.