# Making a snake in command line - multithreading?

Tags: c

I'm trying to make a snake in the command line when the snake itself is created with O's and the apples are dots "."'s. Now... I know hot to get arrow keys and I know the algorithm but the snake needs to move (using Sleep and animations) and also have getch() on all the time. How do I do that ? Isn't that multithreading ? I just need the thread with the getch() and to operate it with other functions.

Comment: Don't make `snakes`.  Make `snacks` instead.

Comment: @ajay I'm wondering how to make animation (using sleep) while preparing for getch();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `kbhit` (or `_getch` and `_kbhit`) to peek and see if there are some keys pressed. And only if there are some, get it with `getch`. Also see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15603082/how-to-use-kbhit-and-getch-c-programming) question and answer for an example.

Comment: Aren't those only for Windows?  I think the OP is talking about `getch()` from `curses.h`.  [This](http://www.flipcode.com/archives/_kbhit_for_Linux.shtml) article explains how to get `_kbhit` functionality under `curses`.

Comment: Can you determine which key was pressed using kbhit?